# spring4 beans injection in bean constructor using @Autowired

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, dependency-injection, autowired

I have Class object constructor where one of parameters is `Long parent_id` cause object is self related as follow:

```
public class Folder {
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Folder parent;

}
```

When I try to deserialize with `Gson` I have to create object using Gson. Using parent_id I would like to creat new object of Folder to apply it to `parent` element.

When I try to do:

```
@Transient @Autowired public Folder folderDao;

someMethod() {
    folderDao.get(9L);
}
```

My dao class:

```
@Override
public T get(Long id) {
    System.out.println("_Trying to get by id...");
    return (T) getCurrentSession().get(entityClass, id);
}
```

I got a `NullPointerException` 
and this line is not excecuted: `System.out.println("_Trying to get by id...");`

I dont know why. Can anyone help me? What Am I doing wrong with Spring Injection.

By the way: My controllers have `@Transactional` annotation

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `skeletonElementDao` is null.

Should you autowire the dao, not the folder?

```
@Autowired 
private SkeletonElementDao skeletonElementDao;
```

instead of

```
@Transient @Autowired public Folder folder;
```

Comment: Then the folderDao is probably null. Are you making the call from correctly initialized bean? Somehow autowiring did not wire folderDao?

Comment: Yes. It is null. I do not know why? In controllers it works ok? It dosnt work in model. I' dont know why.

Comment: Is that someMethod on Model class? Wouldn't work since autowiring is for beans initialized on bean context.

Comment: Yes. someMethod is in constructor inside the model/entity. What do You mean by `bean context`? Is it controller, or what?

Comment: I think you can do that on controller, but I would prefer separate service layer for this kind of actions on larger application.